# Eclipse compiling fine but refuses to find class files

Tags: eclipse

I've replaced a few files in my Eclipse Luna Java project (simply copying externally from my other dev computer to my dev folder connected to the internet for revision control) and now Eclipse refuses to show any .class file in the build folder and refuses to run my ant file saying it cannot find xxx.class

The files are there just in Navigator they are not visible and running my ant file from within Eclipse fails saying it cannot find the class files.

Command line running ant works fine, it's just all mixed up and I'd rather not recreate the project again.

I've tried cleaning, closing, refreshing, updating class path, etc.

Even when I change the build folder it fails to create the class files now.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is  "build automatically" under "Project" menu enabled

Comment: Yes, as I said Ecliopse is compiling them and putting them in the correct place, just Eclipse is not showing them and fails my ant script running from within Eclipse saying it can't find them.

Answer (score 0):

My fault, my path had JDK8 first and Eclipse was set to JDK7. Causing Ant to throw a wobbler within Eclipse.